# NullPointerException when mocking a QueryBuilder

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, mocking, mockito, query-builder

**Problem:**

I'm trying to create a test, using Mockito. This test Mocks a QueryBuilder and try to verify if everything is ok. 
But I am getting **"java.lang.NullPointerException"**. It seems like something hasn't been initialized, but i can't see what it is.

**Code:**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.StrictStubs.class)
public class AcademicJPADAOTest {

    @Mock
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    @Mock
    private CriteriaBuilder cb;
    @Mock
    private CriteriaQuery<Academic> cq;
    @Mock
    private Root<Academic> root;

    @InjectMocks
    AcademicJPADAO academicjpadao;

    private String passwdcode = "83997689-22b6-4a7e-a801";


    @Test
    public void retrieveByPasswordCodeTest() throws PersistentObjectNotFoundException, MultiplePersistentObjectsFoundException {

        Academic academic = new Academic();

        when(entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder()).thenReturn(cb);
        when(cb.createQuery(Academic.class)).thenReturn(cq);
        when(cq.from(Academic.class)).thenReturn(root);
        when(cq.where(cb.equal(root.get(Academic_.passwordCode), passwdcode))).thenReturn(cq);

        when(academicjpadao.getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getSingleResult()).thenReturn(academic);

        academicjpadao.retrieveByPasswordCode(passwdcode);

        verify(entityManager, times(1)).getCriteriaBuilder();

    }
}
```

**Line error:**

```
when(academicjpadao.getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getSingleResult()).thenReturn(academic);
```

Comment: Null pointer comes when your values miss matches in when(..).

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: `academicjpadao.getEntityManager().createQuery(cq)` returns null - there is no behaviour specified for `entityManager.createQuery()`. Subsequent call of `getSingleResult` ends with NPE. What is surprising about that?

Comment: @Jaadu I can imagine that, the question is, what's miss matching ? haha

Comment: @Lesiak Are you saying that i have to separate this when(..) , into two different parts? one specifying the return of `entityManager.createQuery()`, and the other one specifying the result of `getSingleResult` ?

Comment: @Mr.Moon yes, if you have a chained call, you need when / thenReturn for each part

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `academicjpadao` isn't injected correctly in this part :

```
 @InjectMocks
 AcademicJPADAO academicjpadao;
```

so Use `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks` to initiate the `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` objects.so you have to add to your class this method :

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i didnt work. Because i'm using "@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.StrictStubs.class)", and it already inits the Mocks